# Celluloid output is out of order and formatted erratically

Tags: ruby

I have a working script that utilizes celluloid for network parallelism. What it does is scan a range of IP addresses and tries to connect to them. It will output either ip_addr: Filtered, Refused, or Connected. The only problem with the script is the way the results are printed. Instead of being in order, like so:

`192.168.0.20: Filtered
 192.168.0.21: Connected`

It outputs like this:

`192.168.0.65 Firewalled!
    192.168.0.11 Firewalled!192.168.0.183 Firewalled!192.168.0.28 Firewalled!192.168.0.171 Firewalled!192.168.0.228 Firewalled!
192.168.0.238 Firewalled!192.168.0.85 Firewalled!192.168.0.148 Firewalled!192.168.0.154 Firewalled!192.168.0.76 Firewalled!192.168.0.115 Firewalled!`

```
192.168.0.215 Firewalled!
```

In the terminal. As you can see it's completely erratic. Here's the relevant code:

```
    def connect
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(@host, nil)
    sock = Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)


    begin
        sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(@port, addr[0][3]))

    rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS
        resp = IO.select(nil, [sock], nil, @timeout.to_i)

        if resp.nil?
            puts "#{@host} Firewalled!"
        end

        begin
            if sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(@port, addr[0][3]))
                puts "#{@host} Connected!"
            end

        rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
            puts "#{@host} Refused!"

        rescue
            false
        end
    end
    sock
end

range = []
main = Ranger.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])


(1..254).each do |oct|
    range << main.strplace(ARGV[0]+oct.to_s)
end


threads = []

range.each do |ip|
    threads << Thread.new do
        scan = Ranger.new(ip, ARGV[1])
        scan.future :connect
    end
end

threads.each do |thread|
    thread.join
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. You see, puts is not thread-safe. When you call puts, it does 2 things: a) It prints whatever you want to the screen and b) It inserts a newline \n at the end. So one thread (thread A) could do a) but then stop and another thread (thread B) could also do a), then the operating system might go again to thread A which will do b) etc., thus producing the input you're seeing.

So the solution would be to replace all instances of puts with "print whatever-you-want \n". For example, this:

```
puts "#{@host} Firewalled!"
```

could be converted into:

```
print "#{@host} Firewalled!\n"
```

Unlike puts, print is thread-safe and cannot be interrupted before it's complete.

Comment: Oh wow that's simpler then I thought. I can't believe I didn't figure that one out. Thanks very much :D